# Is there a way to see what I wrote on the chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have registered into a Minecraft server, but now I don't remember my password. Knowing that this server uses the /register system, I thought about looking at the chat log in the .minecraft folder, but it only has what I have been shown and not what I wrote. Does the game register what I wrote in the chat? If so, where can I see the logs?

Comment: What server are you on that you need a password?

Answer (score 2):

In your Minecraft data folder (by default `%appdata%/.minecraft` on Windows and `~/.minecraft` on Linux) there is a folder called `logs`. It contains the file `latest.log` for your most recent launch of Minecraft and a lot of `.gz` archives containing log files of previous launches. In one of those should be the chat log that you want.

If you want to search through all of them, you can copy the archives into a different folder, unpack them all there and use for example Notepad++ to search through all files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work since the person that posted this posted it 4 years ago. But you need to go to

-/Library/Application Support/minecraft (Your Minecraft folder)

Then in that folder go to Logs. Most of the files should be zipped so you'll have to unzip them. But in those files should be all of your chat history.

Comment: What path is that? Is that the path you set in your launcher profile? If yes, it's of course completely different for other people. Also, is that the complete path? It's definitely not a valid Windows path and even without the `-` it would be one that doesn't usually exist on Linux.